# QTP, how to Auto save scripts and Function Libraries after updating

Tags: qtp, autosave

Is there anyway to make Quick Test Professional(QTP) auto save updates for Scripts ?

your help is highly appreciated.

thanks Manaysah

Comment: Do anyone can help me, the QTP Crashes many times and I want a method or way to recover my scripts that I had created or someway to auto save each update to the script. 

your help is highly appreciated ....

Comment: Please explain your question briefly ....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm using QTP 11, and sometimes the QTP crashes or hanging and needs to end its process from task manager, so unsaved scripts will lost,  I just want if there is a way to make it auto save or if I can recover unsaved work. 
like in MS office ... 


thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is not a solution for your questions, but an alternative approach. I personally am not a fan of QTP script editor.  I use Notepad++ to edit the qtp scripts. It has nice syntax support for vb and auto-completion comes in handy. I use the backup feature in NPP, just in case I want to look at what I did hours back.

The disadvantage of this approach is that I have to close the *.qfl file in the script editor and open it back again which loses the check points while debugging.

Also if you have any version control software, make use of it to store your scripts.

Comment: Thanks , but this not solve the issue because of notepad not support OR auto completion like QTP action ...

Answer (score 0):

Use VSCODE. It has auto save option, code high lighting via add ins, and solid git integration. Much better than what UFT offers.